# How to pass string value to NSString as it is

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I am creating JSON objects to a textfile, and I am copy-pasting it as is inside the `""`

Here is the **textJSON**

```
{
        "product_id": 12,
        "product_title": "T-Shirt",
        "brand": {
            "brand_id": 3,
            "brand_name": "Armani"
        }
}
```

Here how I am trying to pass it to NSString and I am getting an error for `unterminated string literal`

```
var stringJSON:NSString = "{
        "product_id": 12,
        "product_title": "T-Shirt",
        "brand": {
            "brand_id": 3,
            "brand_name": "Armani"
        }
}"
```

I know that I can fix it by removing the newlines and doing it step by step, but is there anyway so I can get this value to my `NSString` without inspecting every mistake on copy-paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a json minifier (such as http://www.httputility.net/json-minifier.aspx) and then replace any `"` with `\"`.

Comment: when installl HOStringSense, after use JSON Minifier, copy all string and paste to XCode, you not need to replace any " with \" @eridb

Comment: @ABáo I see your point, but I don't want to install extra plugins to my Xcode. I am just testing some methods right now, that's why.

Answer (score 1):

Install `HOStringSense-for-Xcode` for XCode it's easy way to add string in well format by simply copy and paste action

home page: https://github.com/holtwick/HOStringSense-for-Xcode

Answer (score 1):

Swift does not support multiline String literals. You have to remove all newlines and escape all quotes. Your string will look like this:

```
var stringJSON:NSString = "{ \"product_id\": 12, \"product_title\": \"T-Shirt\", \"brand\": {\"brand_id\": 3, \"brand_name\": \"Armani\" } }"
```

If you have to do this to multiple strings, there's likely a better way for you to store your JSON rather than hardcoding it into your program. Loading from a .json file wouldn't have these problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is happening because of the quotation marks. I modified the code as follows:-

```
var stringJSON:NSString = "{\"product_id\": 12,\"product_title\": \"T-Shirt\",\"brand\": {\"brand_id\": 3,\"brand_name\": \"Armani\"}}"
```

and it seems to be working. When you add a quote inside a string, it considers it to be the end of the string. Please change all quotes(") inside your string to quotes with escape characters(\"). Also I try to avoid spreading strings over multiple lines.

Hope this helps!